# How to instantiate an existing QGIS plugin toolbar

Tags: python, toolbar, qgis

What is the Python method to "turn on" existing QGIS 3 toolbars, as you manually do when you right-click in the toolbar area and select the toolbar that you want to appear?

[image]

Comment: Please check https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html

Comment: @ParthS007 Thanks for your comment. But unless I'm missing something, the document (relevant for QGIS 2, not QGIS 3) doesn't mention anything about instantiating toolbars using Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So depending on the toolbar that you want to show or hide, you can do the following: `iface.databaseToolBar().show()` or `iface.databaseToolBar().hide()`

You can find the available toolbars in the [API](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html). Just do a search for “ToolBar()”

Comment: That's it! Thanks, James.